# visual basic for application - error handling

Tags: vba

I have never worked with VBA, therefore this could by an easy task, but I can't get it working :-) Simply I need to catch a run time error in following code :

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("(X)").Unprotect
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("(X)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("F18").Select
'here comes the error
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$X$310").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
Sheets("(40 UKÁŽKA)").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the error or error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to old school error handling.

What you are looking for is either

```
Sub MySub()
  On Error Resume Next
    DoMyStuff()
End Sub
```

if you want to swallow this issue, e.g equivalent of Try Catch End

or

```
Sub MySub()
  On Error Goto ErrorHandler
    DoMyStuff()
  KeepGoing :
    DoSomeMoreStuffAnyway() 
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  HandleTheError()
Exit Sub
```

You can get the Error number from the variable Err
You can also fix and call Resume to go to the next line of code after the error happened
You can also do Resume To a lable e.g. Resume KeepGoing in the above.

More info here [MSDN VBA Error Handling](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571)

Answer (score 2):

Use `On Error`. See **[this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)** for a good discussion of the topic.

```
      On Error GoTo ErrHandler

      <do things>

      On Error GoTo  0 'Turn default error handling back on

      Exit Sub

 ErrHandler:

     If Error.Number = xxxx Then

         <error processing>

     End If

     (then Resume )(or  Resume Next) (or do nothing & let sub end)

 End Sub
```